# Xcode hanging on Analzying Generating dSYM file

Tags: xcode

*** Hi - Please ignore this.  There was nothing wrong with the file -  it was very large and needed 30 mins to compile.  Cheers! (That's what you get when you're used to small files)

I'm just a newbie and looking for some advice.  I'm using Xcode 4.3.2.

Previously, I've had absolutely no problem archiving my projects and uploading them on the AppStore.  Today, it's just not working and I don't even know where to start looking.  I've changed no settings, and I tried another project and it archived just fine, so I'm assuming it's not my Xcode or any of my certificates.

When I tried to build the App, it just stopped on

"Compiling 9 o 9 source files... " and refused to go any further than that.

So I tried to Analyze the file, and it now hangs on:

"Generating dSYM file"

I'm obviously doing something stupid, and I don't even know where to go after this, and I have tried to google and everything else.  I really would be grateful for any hints on where I could look or solve this.

If there's a Xcode developer in Perth, Western Australia - I'd be willing to pay for help because I'm that desperate.  I'm not writing a killer App or anything like that, it's just that the whole thing is driving me nuts.

Cheers
Jacqueline

Comment: I just started to see this exact problem in Xcode 4.4. Our file is not huge either.. Anyone else?

Comment: For anyone else that gets stuck as I did: check `ps auxwww | grep clang` on the spun process, find out if there's a consistent file it's working on, then comment out the body of that file (keeping nil implementations for public interface). If that works, you can find out where the issue is inside a method. For us, we had a custom UIFont we applied to a whole bunch of labels, and used a chained `label1.font = label2.font = … = customUIFont` style of assignment (there were 20 labels). That borked Xcode 4.4. Xcode 4.3 and earlier; no problem at all.